# Display Category names on React

Tags: reactjs

I have a product table that has the ff:

- id - AUTO_INCREMENT
- date
- amount
- description
- cat_id

and a category table that has the ff:

- id - AUTO_INCREMENT
- name
- amount

Now on my react app I am trying to pull up a select statement that will display the categories name to the given list of category names. by default if there is no category inserted within the product table it must return none.

So I created a helper function:

```
const selectViaId = function(id){
  sequelize.query('SELECT categories.name FROM `categories` LEFT JOIN products on products.category_id = categories.id', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(catnames => {
      callback(catnames);
    });
};
```

How do I list all these category names on my select statement that uses two tables in react?

For instance:

```
{ categories.map(item => {
  return <div className="cat-name">{this.props.item.cat.name}</div>;
}
```

So if the category_id from the products table it must return "none" if it's not empty it must return the category name from the list inside that div that is equal to the id of the cateogories table....Sorry newbie here.

Comment: Please elaborate on what’s wrong with the code you have currently in your question. What does it output or what doesn’t work, and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: I am trying to select all the category names from categories tables that are equal to the product category_id and then display them within my div there.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understood, however, I hope you're trying to implement like this?

```
{ 
 categories.map(item => {
   return selectViaId(item.id) 
     ? 
   (<div className="cat-name">{this.props.item.cat.name}</div>) 
    : 
   '';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a function that will return required data in a callback.

```
export const selectViaId = function(id, callback){
  sequelize.query('SELECT categories.name FROM `categories` LEFT JOIN products on products.category_id = categories.id', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(catnames => {
      callback(catnames);
    });
};
```

If I understood correctly now you only need to use it in a component. Use React state to do so.

```
import React from "react";
import { selectViaId } from "path/to/this/function";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categories: [] // important to set initial value
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // you will probably gonna do this in some click handler 
    selectViaId(4, categories => this.setState({ categories }));
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.categories.map(item => (
      <div className="cat-name">{this.props.item.cat.name}</div>
    ));
  }
}
```